# JavaScript - updating <textarea> value under certian conditions and append it to a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pagaraph (`p`) appended to a `div`, that shows `<textarea>` value, and it works well.

The `<textarea>` supposed to be a part of a page that allows the users to add new lines to the text content, exactly like how we can type `<br>` for a new line in `textarea`.
But since they don't know how to do that I'm trying to make it easy for them by:

> (typing plus sign twice ++ *OR* pressing Enter on the keyboard)

**Both** should add a `<br>` tag automatically while typing `(onkeyup)`...

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var textareaPreview = document.querySelector('.textarea-preview');
var currentText;

textarea.onkeyup = function(){
    currentText = textarea.value;
    var previewAsString = "<p class='p-preview'>" + currentText + "</p>" 
    textareaPreview.innerHTML = previewAsString;
};
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Type here.."></textarea>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="textarea-preview"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is to replace `++` and newlines with `<br>`:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var textareaPreview = document.querySelector('.textarea-preview');
var currentText;

textarea.onkeyup = function(){
    currentText = textarea.value;
    var previewAsString = "<p class='p-preview'>" + currentText.replace(/\+\+|\n/g, '<br>') + "</p>" 
    textareaPreview.innerHTML = previewAsString;
};
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Type here.."></textarea>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <div class="textarea-preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So I was thinking if I have more conditions? like text between two starts is bold, etc... Lke how asking a question on Stackoverflow works, for the basic things only, 3 4 features: new line, text bold, italic, em.

Comment: It has the same sort of thing, only with much more complicated logic. Look into markdown parsing: https://www.google.com/search?q=markdown+parsing